# Places after decimal points discarded when extracting numbers from strings

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

I'd like to extract weight values from strings with the unit and the time of measurement using tidyverse.

My dataset is like as below:

```
df <- tibble(ID = c("A","B","C"), 
             Weight = c("45kg^20221120", "51.5kg^20221015", "66.05kg^20221020"))

------
A tibble: 3 × 2
  ID    Weight          
  <chr> <chr>           
1 A     45kg^20221120   
2 B     11.5kg^20221015 
3 C     66.05kg^20221020
```

I use stringr in the tidyverse package with regular expressions.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(Weight = as.numeric(str_extract(Measurement, "(\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)(?=kg)")))

----------
A tibble: 3 × 3
  ID    Measurement      Weight
  <chr> <chr>             <dbl>
1 A     45kg^20221120      45  
2 B     11.5kg^20221015    11.5
3 C     66.05kg^20221020   66.0
```

The second decimal place of C (.0**5**) doesn't extracted.
What's wrong with my code?
Any answers or comments are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing wrong. Try `pull(Weight)` and see the result. It's just showing till first decimal.

Comment: *Sidenote:* If `kg` is meant for both, int & float, rather try e.g. [`"\\d+\\.?\\d*(?=kg)"`](https://regex101.com/r/2BpF07/1) (in [your current pattern](https://regex101.com/r/9cRSPk/1) the left side of the alternation is without condition).

Comment: Thanks @bobblebubble. I'm not sure whether the float class matters in the R language, is it distinguished to usual numeric class?

Comment: @KintensT My comment was just related to your regex pattern. If you match `a|b(?=c)` the *lookahead* works just on the right side of the alternation. To make it work for both, use a [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap): `(?:a|b)(?=c)` Or if possible  without alternation. E.g. like mentioned for this: `\d+\.?\d*(?=kg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was extracted, however tibble is rounding it for 66.0 for easy display.

You can see it if you transform it in `data.frame` or if you `View` it

### Solution

[Check here](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/articles/numbers.html)

### Check this

```
df %>%
  mutate(Weight = as.numeric(str_extract(Measurement, "(\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)(?=kg)"))) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

### Output

```
#>   ID      Measurement Weight
#> 1  A    45kg^20221120  45.00
#> 2  B  51.5kg^20221015  51.50
#> 3  C 66.05kg^20221020  66.05
```

### Or check this

```
df %>%
  mutate(Weight = as.numeric(str_extract(Measurement, "(\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)(?=kg)"))) %>% 
  View()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try to pull all the data out of the string at once with `extract`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(ID = c("A","B","C"), 
             Weight = c("45kg^20221120", "51.5kg^20221015", "66.05kg^20221020"))

df |>
  extract(col = Weight, 
          into = c("weight", "unit", "date"),
          regex = "(.*)(kg)\\^(.*$)", 
          remove = TRUE, 
          convert = TRUE) |>
  mutate(date = lubridate::ymd(date))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   ID    weight unit  date      
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <chr> <date>    
#> 1 A       45   kg    2022-11-20
#> 2 B       51.5 kg    2022-10-15
#> 3 C       66.0 kg    2022-10-20
```

Note that, as stated in the comments, the .05 is just not printing, but is present in the data.

Comment: This will be super useful in the situation that requires separating or extracting multiple factors. Thanks a lot!